# Зачем нужен интерфейс?

Tags: java, ооп

Зачем в java интерфейс, если есть абстрактные классы? Кроме множественного наследования, в чем главные различия?

Comment: @GenCloud задавать "глупые" вопросы не плохо, а плохо - не понимать. Вы уверены , что знаете ответ на этот вопрос ?

Comment: Никто не вспомнил, что абстрактный класс позволяет хранить **состояние** объекта (в полях), а вот интерфейс - нет.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Разница в концепции.

**Абстрактные классы** помогают создавать иерархию с общими чертами. Важным тут является именно связь родитель — наследник. Например абстрактный класс «птица», ее наследники — конкретные виды птиц.

При использовании нам не важно, какая именно птица будет — мы используем ссылку с типом абстрактного класса. И используем методы «кричать», «ходить», «летать». Все ок, но что если не все птицы умеют летать? Например страус, пингвин.

Здесь нам могут помочь **интерфейсы**, которым не важна связь родитель — наследник, они задают правила поведения. Мы можем выделить метод «летать» в интерфейс и реализовать его у тех птиц, которые могут летать; при этом каждая птица может летать характерным только для нее способом. Так же мы сможем в будущем реализовать этот интерфейс у самолета и определить его способ полета.

Например, у нас на острове группа зверей, птиц, машин и нам надо переправить их на другой остров. В этом случае это сделают те, кто реализует интерфейс с методом «летать».

И здесь мы получаем две ветви полиморфизма, одна задает связь родитель —наследник, вторая — поведение.

Answer (score 4):

Допустим, есть три экземпляра классов лошадь, машина, лодка. Все они могут реализовывать интерфейс "перевозка людей". И не важно, каким способом каждый из объектов это делает. Главное, что обязан делать.
Когда надо "перевезти людей", по интерфейсу мы можем обратиться к тем объектам, которые его могут реализовать.
Кроме того, интерфейсная ссылка, указывая на экземпляр класса, сохраняет его от сборки мусора, когда ссылок на него не осталось.

Answer (score 2):

Реализации модульности, слабой связанность. Отличие от абстрактного класса - в JVM нет множественного наследования и конкретный класс может наследовать только от одного абстрактного. А вот implement интерфейсов - может, сколько угодно.

Comment: я написал это в своем вопросе. невнимательно прочитали

Comment: Ну, вообще не сколько угодно) 67 000 интерфейсов вы не сможете реализовать в одном классе - JVM не позволит. А вот 65 000 - пожалуйста)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб всё... пора закрывать Java. Ну это же фуу, не способность реализовать 67000 интерфейсов. Дилетанто!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ага, а ещё она сообщения об ошибках неправильные пишет( Был недавно случай, когда с меня требовала она 8 версию, вместо того, чтобы объяснить, что надо код не в интерфейс а в класс пихать(

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, интерфейсы в `java` могут содержать только абстрактные методы и никакой реализации. В них нет конструкторов. В абстрактном классе может быть 1 или больше абстрактных методов, и также он может иметь методы с реализацией. В АК есть конструктор.

Класс может наследовать много интерфейсов, но только один класс.

Пишу на Scala, там используются трейты вместо интерфейсов.
Вышесказанное относится и к трейтам тоже, но там еще можно прокинуть type class в него, и плюс в нем могут быть абстрактные и реализованные методы.

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov выбор языка на парадигмы не влияет

Comment: @Etki, не понял вас

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov да не в имплементации проблема, проблема в том, что вы концепцию не понимаете. Формальные различия в применении здесь может любой описать.

Comment: @etki, просветите меня пожалуйста, какую я там концепцию не понимаю?

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov я про контракты