# Зачем нужны интерфейсы в PHP?

Tags: php, интерфейс

В книге написано, что каждый класс, который расширяет интерфейс, обязан реализовать абстрактные классы. Можно же без интерфейса объявить класс?

Например:

```
 Interface seo {
Public function keywords()
}
Class StaticPage implements seo{
Public function keywords (){....}
}
```

Comment: Абстрактные методы*****

Comment: Интерфейc - это термин не PHP, а Объектно-Ориентированного Программирования (ООП) в целом. Вот тут вы можете найти объяснение, для чего нужны интерфейсы на примере языка Java https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136909/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F-java-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83

Answer (score 0):

> который расширяет интерфейс,

Интерфейс не расширяют их реализуют. Расширяют классы. 
Если в двух словах интерфейс определяет некие правила.

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь приведен хороший пример с птицами

[Зачем нужен интерфейс?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569783/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)

Бывают исключения, когда не нужно что-либо выполнять, а абстрактный класс говорит что ты обязан это сделать